# Android RadioGroup. Forced buttons in one column?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I want a `RadioGroup` with various `RadioButtons` displayed in two columns. But it seems that `RadioGroup` forces the `RadioButtons` to be displayed in just one column. Is there a way to get the buttons displayed in two columns?

For example, this xml code would put the four buttons in a `square form`, but inside the RadioGroup they are all in `one column`.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radio1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio4"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radio2"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: RadioGroup extends LinearLayout, so simply this cannot be done..
You can override RelativeLayout and perform some check/uncheck logic in it.

Comment: @convexHull And how could I override it, and get these buttons as a `square form`?

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html
Create some class (for example RelativeRadioGroup) and let it extends RelativeLayout.
Check out source code for RadioGroup to see how to implement additional logic for buttons checking/unchecking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying Radio buttons in multiple columns using Radio group cannot be done.However this can be in a different way as below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
            android:text="Button2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

set View.onClickListener for all radio buttons and handle setting check/uncheck status in your code.